# how to enable/disable checkbox or edidText in listview array adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-arrayadapter, android-checkbox

How would I enable or disable checkbox or edittext in a listView programmatically?

Currently, `onTouch()`, I `setEnable(false)` based on few flags(flags set outside the adapter). But, if the flags are different then I need to enable them back. 
However, here, after I set it to false, anytime I touch checkbox or edittext, the `onTouchListener()` won't trigger. Which seems to make sense since I disabled.

So what is the best way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?, there are different ways to do this

Comment: Basically, when the fragment starts the list view, I don't want to enable editing. The editing is only allowed, when a button is clicked. This button is also part of the fragment. So to summarize it, a way to programmatically enable or disable editting using a button in a fragment. I was told that it's not a good practice to get the list view id, then the view outside the adapter, not sure if this is right.

Comment: So you have a flag outside the adapter but you adapter can see it?, you could onTouch if disable, dont do anything and request focus on the button

Comment: Yes, I pass some flags. the thing is if i disabled editing using setEnable(false), then onTouch won't get triggered during the touch, so i can't request focus again.